Including all constraints in a geometry problem
I'm trying to solve this geometry problem using GeometricScene:
Find angle x:

Here's my (incomplete) code:
scene = GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x}}, {GeometricAssertion[
     Triangle[{a, b, c}], "Counterclockwise"],
    GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{a, d, c}], "Counterclockwise"],
    GeometricAssertion[Line[{b, c}], "Horizontal"],
    Line[{b, e}],
    Line[{e, d}],
    PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == \[Alpha],
    PlanarAngle[{d, a, c}] == 2 \[Alpha],
    PlanarAngle[{e, b, c}] == \[Beta],
    PlanarAngle[{e, b, a}] == 2 \[Beta],
    CollinearPoints[{b, f, e}],
    CollinearPoints[{a, f, c}]
    (* PlanarAngle[{a,d,e}]== 2 \[Phi],*)
    }];
RandomInstance[scene]

As I've done in similar problems, I build up the constraints one by one, seeing the RandomInstance become more and more constrained.  Once I get all the constraints imposed, I use:
Replace[x, %["Quantities"]]

to compute x.
All works fine until I try to impose
PlanarAngle[{a,d,e}]== 2 \[Phi]

which Mathematica will not then render.  (I don't even try adding the remaining constraints.)
I believe I've defined sufficient elements and constraints up to the stated condition.
How can I add all the required constraints and thereby solve this geometry problem?
Incidentally:
$VersionNumber

13.1

Sometimes it fails to fulfil this assertion GeometricAssertion[{{b}, {c}}, {"OppositeSides", Line[{a, d}]}] (maybe a bug in RandomInstance) in which case the angle x is not unique.
scene = GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, d, e, 
     f}, {x, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Phi], theta}}, {GeometricAssertion[
     Triangle[{a, b, c}], "Counterclockwise"], 
    GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{a, d, c}], "Counterclockwise"], 
    GeometricAssertion[Line[{b, c}], "Horizontal"], Line[{b, e}], 
    Line[{e, d}], PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == \[Alpha], 
    PlanarAngle[{d, a, c}] == 2 \[Alpha], 
    PlanarAngle[{e, b, c}] == \[Beta], 
    PlanarAngle[{e, b, a}] == 2 \[Beta], CollinearPoints[{b, f, e}], 
    CollinearPoints[{a, f, c}],
    PlanarAngle[{a, d, e}] == 2 \[Phi], 
    PlanarAngle[{e, d, c}] == \[Phi], PlanarAngle[{d, c, b}] == theta,
     PlanarAngle[{a, f, e}] == 126 Degree, 
    PlanarAngle[{b, e, d}] == x, 
    PlanarAngle[{d, c, a}] == 180 Degree - 2 theta, 
    GeometricAssertion[{Line[{b, e}], Line[{a, c}]}, {"Concurrent", 
      f}], GeometricAssertion[{{b}, {c}}, {"OppositeSides", 
      Line[{a, d}]}]}];
RandomInstance[scene]
Replace[x, %["Quantities"]]/Pi*180



42.


Perfect.  My silly mistake not to include the variables in the preface.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$).

@DavidG.Stork It is not necessary, it works well for me even with {x}, if it is the only parameter of interest.

Addition of symbolic quantities helps. The following works in 14.0 on Windows.
scene = GeometricScene[{{a, b, c, d, e, 
 f}, {x, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Phi]}}, {GeometricAssertion[
 Triangle[{a, b, c}], "Counterclockwise"], 
GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{a, d, c}], "Counterclockwise"], 
GeometricAssertion[Line[{b, c}], "Horizontal"], Line[{b, e}], 
Line[{e, d}], PlanarAngle[{b, a, d}] == \[Alpha], 
PlanarAngle[{d, a, c}] == 2  \[Alpha], 
PlanarAngle[{a, d, e}] == 2  \[Phi], 
PlanarAngle[{e, b, c}] == \[Beta], 
PlanarAngle[{e, b, a}] == 2  \[Beta], CollinearPoints[{b, f, e}], 
CollinearPoints[{a, f, c}]
RandomInstance[scene]

Don't know how to present a picture.

Your code works and gives a figure, once I fixed your syntax errors. ... CollinearPoints[{a, f, c}]}];  Thanks! ($+1$)
